# TypeError save() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)

Tags: django, django-forms, geoip

i have in my views.py

```
def status_set(request):
    ip_address= request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
    if request.method == "POST":
        rform = registerForm(data = request.POST)
        if rform.is_valid():
            register = rform.save(commit=False)
            register.user=request.user
            register.save()
            return render_to_response('home.html')
    else:
        rform = registerForm() 
    return render_to_response('status_set.html',{'rform':rform})
```

and in forms.py ihave

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP


    class registerForm(forms.ModelForm): 
        class Meta:
            model=register
            fields = ('Availability', 'Status')

        def save(self,ip_address, *args, **kwargs):
            g = GeoIP()
            lat, lon = g.lat_lon('ip_address')
            user_location = super(registerForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user_location.latitude = lat
            user_location.longitude = lon
            user_location.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and when i tried to submitt the form it says

TypeError at /status-set/
save() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)
iam unable to find the solution for that. what is the possible reason for this 
i think i have to pass the ip address as an argument any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ip_address parameter is required so you must provide it:

```
register.save(ip_address)
```

Also, you don't actually appear to be using the ip_address parameter inside the method. Probably you should not have quotes aroung `ip_address` in the method you are calling:

```
lat, lon = g.lat_lon(ip_address)
```

Comment: Mark's answer is correct... in your original code 1) you don't pass `ip_address` from the view to the form's save method, and 2) even if you did, calling `g.lat_lon('ip_address')` (note the single quotes) means you are passing a string to g.lat_lon(), not the ip_address parameter.